# next.js and mongodb coherence?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I googled a lot but still have no clear solution to my issue.
Connecting to MongoDB, usually you establish a connection and after the job is done you close it.
Since next.js (and probably node.js) is single threaded. Sometimes it happens that there are two requests processed async while one request established the connection to the database, the otherone is closing the exact same connection. So the first request runs into an Topology closed exception. I have the feeling that the mongodb driver client is shared.
Is there something I did not understood correct in this?

```
try {
        await client.connect()
        const database = client.db("test")
        const collection = database.collection("test")
        const newDataset = await collection.insertOne({})
        return newDataset.insertedId.toString()
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
```

Comment: Why close the connection in the first place? Ive seen hunders of examples where in a express route every time a request is received a connection is opend and closed. This just takes time and has no benefit. Do it the other way around: First establish a db connection, then start you express/http server. And keep the connection open. This open/closing nonesense makes no sense. If you app needs a db connection: Open it, and keep it open.

Comment: it will automatically run into the timeout isnt it?

Comment: No, the timeout "applies" only for the connection attempt and not allready for a established connection. If the connection is closed (because the db server crashes or network issues) you run into the timeout. But not if both sides are working correctly. The timeout is not between queries. Connect to the db and do nothing for 5 minutes is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Marc thanks thats the answer, could you create an answer so i can tick it?

Comment: If you insist ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments stated, ive seen a lot of examples & questions here on stackoverflow where in each received request (example below) a database connection is established. This has no benefits and is "bad" because it just takes time and makes no sense. E.g:

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect("...", (err, client) => {
     // do what ever you want here
     client.close();
  });
});
```

If you application needs a database connection, establish the connection "in the startup phase" and keep the connection open. There is no reason to open and close the database connection for each request.

```js
const mongodb = require("monogdb");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// some custom init stuff
// e.g. require your route handler etc.

mongodb.MongoClient("...", (err, client) => {

  // do what ever you want with the db connection now
  // e.g. monkey patch it, so you can use it in other files
  // (There are better ways to handle that)
  mongodb.client = client;

  // or the better way
  // pass it as function parameter
  require("./routes")(app, client);
  
  app.listen(8080, () => {
     console.log("http server listening");
  });

});
```

As you can see in the code above, we first create a database connection and then do other stuff. This has some advantages:

1. If your credentials are invalid, your application is not externeal reachable because the http server is not started
2. You have a single connection for all requests
3. Database queries are potential faster because you dont have to wait to establish first a db connection

*NOTE: the code above was "inline coded" here and is not tested.*
But i think its illustrated the concept behind my statement.

Comment: yeah that was basically the answer, let the connection open, in the docu is nothing stated about this "best practice", actually all in all of the examples the connection is being closed right after

Comment: Yeah. I dont know why everyone is doing this "wrong".